# Кнопка в GridView

Tags: yii2

Хочу создать кнопку непосредственно в колонках gridview для работы с ними. Пользователь выбирает на сколько продлить дату(месяц, два или три) и вместо кнопки выходила бы готовая дата. Знаю как прописать в контроллере эту функцию,чтобы выбирало дату, но как вывести кнопки, а после выбора дату?

Answer (score 0):

В массив 'columns' виджета GridView можно указать собственную кнопку. Примерно так:

```
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{check}{view}{update}{delete}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'check' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', ['/site/check', 'id' => $model->id]));
                    },
                ],
            ],
```

Таким образом полный код вставки GridView будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'title',
            'description:html',
            'date:datetime',

            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{check}{view}{update}{delete}',
                'buttons' => [
                    'check' => function ($url, $model) {
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>', ['/site/check', 'id' => $model->id]));
                    },
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а списком не знаете как сделать? Так было бы удобнее, просто придётся три кнопки делать под три значения

Comment: в массиве 'buttons' указывается `'имя кнопки' => анонимная функция`. из этой анонимной функции можно вернуть не просто ссылку с тегом `<а>`, а свой список, да хоть `<select>`, на что фантазии хватит. ну и дальше уже отслеживать выбранное в списке/селекте на JS

Comment: а как для этого столбца задать label ???